# dynamic loop in a hash Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I'm trying to create a dynamic loop within the hash @data below and
can't really seem to figure it out. I'm creating an annotatedtimeline-for-rails using the google  api from here https://github.com/mcommons/annotatedtimeline-for-rails.

The array within the hash @data has to be dynamic i:e the day number has to be generated by a loop and the name of the product  and number are dynamic as well. I'll
try to give an example in the loop below

@numdeployed is a number and comes from a table in the db
i should be generated by the loop

```
@data{
    begin loop
    i.day.ago.to_date => { :foo=>@numdeployed, :bar=>@numdeployed, :barbaz=>@numdeployed, :foobar=>@numdeployed },
    end loop
}
```

The Original Data Hash looks like this

```
@data = {
    1.day.ago.to_date => { :foo=>10, :bar=>40, :barbaz=>10, :foobar=>40 },
    2.day.ago.to_date => { :foo=>10, :bar=>40, :barbaz=>10,:foobar=>40 },
    3.day.ago.to_date => { :foo=>10, :bar=>40, :barbaz=>10,:foobar=>40 },
    4.day.ago.to_date => { :foo=>10, :bar=>40, :barbaz=>10,:foobar=>40 },
    5.day.ago.to_date => { :foo=>10, :bar=>40, :barbaz=>10,:foobar=>40 }
}
```

hope someone can help. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
@data = Hash[
    n.times.map do |i|
        [ (i + 1).day.ago.to_date,  { :foo => 10, :bar => 40, :barbaz => 10, :foobar => 40 } ]
    end
]
```

The `n` is however many pairs you want in your `@data`.